# Unable to install Express using npm in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install express on my node installation using npm. I am doing a local installation. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 in my office environment (i.e. other than a few well known ports everything else would be blocked). I am invoking "npm install" from package.json as a user (not 'sudo' ing). The installation is failing with the following logs.

Comments/solution would be appreciated.

```
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.2
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.1.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/0.0.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/debug
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.2
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.1.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/0.0.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/debug
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.2
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.1.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/0.0.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/debug
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
    npm ERR! Error: Parse Error
    npm ERR!     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1485:20)
    npm ERR!     at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
    npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR! or email it to:
    npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

    npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-20-generic
    npm ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd /home/nvbalaji/nodejs/hb
    npm ERR! node -v v0.8.21
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.12
    npm ERR! code HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT
    npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/nvbalaji/nodejs/hb/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: From the looks of it, I'd say it is a npm-related issue, because it usually cries out that it's not its fault otherwise.

Comment: No ! nothing running on localhost:80

Comment: Sorry, I posted that comment meant for another question. having something running on any port probably has nothing to do with your issue. Sorry.

Comment: I have raised an issue in npm github [https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3213]

Comment: Looks like it's a network issue specific to my office environment. The installation is going smooth once that issue is resolved. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

maybe some processes during global installation
`npm install express -g / npm install -g express`
needs admin permissions for writing files in system folders. try not global installation `npm install express`.

Comment: I am not attempting global install. I am installing inside my app directory

Answer (score 0):

This is how i've worked around it on my installs:

Create a new file called node

```
:\>gedit /usr/local/bin/node
```

Contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /nodejs "$@"

:\>sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/node
```

Try your NPM install again.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested. it doesn't seem to work. BTW, I guess you wanted to mean "sudo chmod **+x** /usr/local/bin/node"

Comment: I updated it, sorry, I don't know the install process better, but that was what I had to do for npm to work for me, but it is looking like yours is more of a express problem, can you install other modules?

Comment: Looks like it is a network issue. Network port was getting blocked once in a while due to some weird policy. Sorry for wasting your time